# Unity - stop spawning new particles without destroying existing ones?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how can i stop spawning new particles without destroying existing ones?

What i tried:
Enabling/Disabling Looping, but then the particleSystem doesn't start spawning new ones.

Comment: your not making sense.  you want to stop spawning new particles but then your saying the particleSystem isn't spawning new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Using the PartycleSystem in-build system (Stop, Play, Pause).

For example, Stop:

`PartycleSystem.Stop` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Stop.html

Comment: This is the correct way to do it +1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to the question itself: using the built-in method `Stop()` from a `ParticleSystem` does not help as it also disables the already spawned particles. The particle system needs to play along until the already spawned ones are dead. This state can be achieved by disabling the particle system's emitter:

```
ParticleSystem ps = ...
ParticleSystem.EmissionModule em = ps.emission;
em.enabled = false;
```

To check then if the last particles have outlived, one can call `ps.IsAlive()`. As the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.IsAlive.html) state:

> Returns true if the Particle System contains live particles or is
> still creating new particles. False if the Particle System has stopped
> emitting particles and all particles are dead.

Beware that looping must be disabled for this to work, which can be achieved in code with:

```
ParticleSystem.MainModule mm = ps.main;
mm.loop = false;
```

or just untick it in the editor.

Comment: Actually no, the answer from @lotan is best because you can use different overrides to achieve the desired effect, in this case a simple line: 

`particleSystem.Stop(true, ParticleSystemStopBehavior.StopEmitting);`

Comment: Yeah at the time of writing i wasn't aware of that param, only `Stop()` does not help. Would have been nice, if that _little_ detail was included in the answer. But thx for adding that.